# tactile sensors and urdf

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a robotic hand, and tactile sensors are available on each finger ... I made a urdf to describe the kinematics of the hand, and now I am thinking of including tactile sensors.

a) Is there a common approach to include tactile sensors in urdf ? Should it be done using some fixed joints for each sensor separately ? (there are about 100 sensors, it will be a pain to include :S)

b) The representation of them should be done using markers I presume ?

Also, any suggestions on the usage of tactile arrays with tf package ? googled but found nothing.

Thank you!
Yaro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34987/tactile-sensors-and-urdf/) by [Yaroslav Tenzer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2468/yaroslav-tenzer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-05-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-05-27**:
It's not very helpful, but have you tried looking at the PR2's touch sensors?

**Comment by [Yaroslav Tenzer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2468/yaroslav-tenzer/) on 2012-05-28**:
I looked into (gripper.urdf.xacro) and (pr2_description/urdf/sensors) but found nothing related to tactile sensors. I looked into (pr2_gripper_sensor_controller) but everything seems to be hard wired and not generalised. Therefore I wonder if anybody used urdf and tf for tactile sensors ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no tag for sensor description in "pure" URDF. There is, however, an URDF extension which can be used to provide to Gazebo sensor information.

See:

- [URDF Sensor tag](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/XML/Sensor) / [URDF Gazebo Extension](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/XML/Gazebo)
- [Understanding PR2 URDF Gazebo Extension](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/UnderstandingPR2URDFGazeboExtension)
- [Adding sensors to PR-2 model](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/AddingSensorsToPR2)

This extension is only here to embed sensor specific data. If you don't have meta-data, adding a frame is enough. And yes, you **will** have to add one frame per sensor to model your sensors (i.e. if you want to compute your sensor position using tf).

You can use [xacro](http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro) to duplicate your sensor 100 times, it should make things easier for you.

However, URDF has not been designed to such as large amount of static frames, so it is probably a suboptimal solution. Maybe [tf2](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf2) could help here...

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2012-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1